# Powershell: Checking if script was invoked with -ErrorAction?

Tags: powershell

Scripts (with CmdletBinding) and cmdlets all have a standard -ErrorAction parameter available when being invoked. Is there a way then, within your script, if indeed you script was invoked with -ErrorAction?

Reason I ask is because I want to know if the automatic variable value for $ErrorActionPreference, as far as your script is concerned, was set by -ErrorAction or if it is coming from your session level.

Comment: Why do you need to know that?

Comment: any final solution with full source code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$ErrorActionPreference` is a variable in the global(session) scope. If you run a script and don't specify the `-ErrorAction` parameter, it inherits the value from the global scope (`$global:ErrorActionPreference`).

If you specify `-ErrorAction` parameter, the `$ErrorActionPreference` is changed for your private scope, meaning it's stays the same through the script except while running code where you specified something else(ex. you call another script with another `-ErrorAction` value).  Example to test:

Test.ps1

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param()

Write-Host "Session: $($global:ErrorActionPreference)"
Write-Host "Script: $($ErrorActionPreference)"
```

Output:

```
PS-ADMIN > $ErrorActionPreference
Continue

PS-ADMIN > .\Test.ps1
Session: Continue
Script: Continue

PS-ADMIN > .\Test.ps1 -ErrorAction Ignore
Session: Continue
Script: Ignore

PS-ADMIN > $ErrorActionPreference
Continue
```

If you wanna test if the script was called with the `-ErrorAction` paramter, you could use ex.

```
if ($global:ErrorActionPreference -ne $ErrorActionPreference) { Write-Host "changed" }
```

If you don't know what scopes is, type this in a powershell console: `Get-Help about_scopes`

Answer (score 3):

Check the $MyInvocation.BoundParameters object. You could use the built-in $PSBoundParameters variable but I found that in some instances it was empty (not directly related to this question), so imo it's safer to use $MyInvocation.

```
function Test-ErrorAction
{
    param()

    if($MyInvocation.BoundParameters.ContainsKey('ErrorAction'))
    {
        'The ErrorAction parameter has been specified'
    }
    else
    {
        'The ErrorAction parameter was not specified'
    }
}

Test-ErrorAction
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to know if the cmdlet was called with the `-ErrorAction` parameter do like this:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param()

if ($myinvocation.Line.ToLower() -match "-erroraction" )
    {
      "yessss"
    }
else
    {
      "nooooo"
    }
```

This is `true` alse when the parameter have same value as the global `$ErrorActionPreference`